# De-allocating 2D array of objects

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am still new to C++ pointers and would feel great if someone can help me out with this situation here:

```
while( true)
{

//some input

//if input is QUIT it quits the program

// some code to calculate how many House objects we need

 House** houses = new House *[numOfHouses];


//some more code 


}
```

Can someone please guide me on how to de-allocate houses (2D array) in this situation?

If my loop runs once and user enters QUIT in the second iteration, I get 8 bytes lost on valgrind check.

If my loop runs twice and user enters QUIT in the third aeration, I get 16 bytes lost on valgrind check.

Thanks

Comment: You loose access to the allocated memory on every iteration in that loop, since you overwrite the old pointer value: `House** houses = new House *[numOfHouses];`.

Comment: yes.. I could figure out that much.. so what will you suggest?

Comment: I would suggest to use a `std::vector<House> houses(numOfHouses);` or if you're sure you need a pointer to `House` use a `std::vector<std..unique_ptr<House>>` (`std::shared_ptr<House>` respectively).

Answer (score 1):

Since you're allocating an array on the heap via `new` the proper way of deallocating it is via

```
House** houses = new House *[numOfHouses];
// Cleanup
delete[] houses;
```

Anyway since you're overwriting the pointer with a new allocation at every loop iteration, you're getting memory leaks.

Either deallocate your memory after you're done inside the loop or use a smart pointer.